# Wordpress form post not showing.

Tags: wordpress, post, publish

I made a wordpress post in HTML using code :

```
&nbsp;
<form action="https://buyvisitors.today/search-results/" method="post" name="myform">Search By :
<input name="product" type="text_area" />Product name
at
<input name="address" type="text_area" />Address<input type="submit" value="Search"/></form>&nbsp;
```

When I click on "Preview" in 'Wordpress' it shows full page correct however when I open actual page at https://buyvisitors.today/ it do not show text boxes and buttons. 
and it give only following output (please help) :

Search By :
Product name
at
Address

Answer (score 0):

Did you insert that HTML code in a regular Wordpress editor, i.e. using "New Post"?

If yes, you should *at least* use "text mode" in the Wordpress editor to be able to write actual HTML code (which in "visual mode" is completely ignored / omitted).

Also, note that there are some Wordpress plugins that make creating and handling of forms very easy, for example "Contact Form 7"